# Class label not present sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier for class_weight

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am using `RandomForestClassifier` from `sklearn.ensemble`. It works when I use it without `class_weight` but when I add `class_weight` It gives this error.

```
lr = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 22,criterion =
                           'entropy',max_depth=5,class_weight={'Sex':2.})

lr.fit(X_train.values[:,1:],Y_train)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-248-411a1c135d08> in <module>
      1 print(X_train)
----> 2 lr.fit(X_train.values[:,1:],Y_train)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/forest.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    273         self.n_outputs_ = y.shape[1]
    274 
--> 275         y, expanded_class_weight = self._validate_y_class_weight(y)
    276 
    277         if getattr(y, "dtype", None) != DOUBLE or not y.flags.contiguous:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/ensemble/forest.py in _validate_y_class_weight(self, y)
    519                     class_weight = self.class_weight
    520                 expanded_class_weight = compute_sample_weight(class_weight,
--> 521                                                               y_original)
    522 
    523         return y, expanded_class_weight

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/class_weight.py in compute_sample_weight(class_weight, y, indices)
    161             weight_k = compute_class_weight(class_weight_k,
    162                                             classes_full,
--> 163                                             y_full)
    164 
    165         weight_k = weight_k[np.searchsorted(classes_full, y_full)]

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/class_weight.py in compute_class_weight(class_weight, classes, y)
     63             i = np.searchsorted(classes, c)
     64             if i >= len(classes) or classes[i] != c:
---> 65                 raise ValueError("Class label {} not present.".format(c))
     66             else:
     67                 weight[i] = class_weight[c]

ValueError: Class label Sex not present.
```

This is my X_train :

`PassengerId  Pclass  Sex    ...     Ticket      Fare     Embarked`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How many classes do you have in `Y_train`?

The `class_weight` concerns the `Y_train` i.e. the labels.

**Example:**

`class_weight={0:1,1:2}`

means weight 1 to class 0 and weight 2 to class 1.

Using `class_weight={'Sex':2.}` is wrong and it refers to `X_train`.

Comment: @RavikantSingh you cannot classify anything if you don't have at least two classes in your `Y_train`

Comment: It's true. You can not define a classification problem with only one class. It does not make sense at all. Maybe you should look for regression (scalar value prediction) models.

Comment: @RavikantSingh what do you mean "it works"? What exactly is the model doing, since there is nothing to classify?

Comment: Probably the OP means that there is no error popping out. However, still a classification is not meaningful when `n_classes < 2`

Comment: I thought of this, but I guess (not sure, though) that the classifier itself should throw an error in case there is only one class present

Comment: @RavikantSingh tell me, what is your goal?

Comment: You don't have one class in your dataset, you have *two* - `1` for survived passengers and `0` otherwise (Titanic dataset). Please *do* spend some time to get familiar with the (very) basics of classification and your dataset first

Comment: @RavikantSingh IMHO you should indeed delete it